# Delete double elements from a list in Lisp

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, duplicates

i have to delete all the double elements from a list in lisp.. here is an example:

```
(A B C D E A A B F G A) => (A B C D E F G)
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 11):

You're looking for [remove-duplicates](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_dup.htm).

Comment: As in: (remove-duplicates '(A B C D E A A B F G A)) Do note however that the last instance of the element is the one that is kept. So for me the result is: '(C D E B F G A)

Comment: ... unless you pass the keyword parameter `:from-end t`.

Answer (score -1):

I am new to lisp as well, but came across this when I was working in my assignment. There is a function 'delete-duplicates' used to remove the duplicates from the list. Since, you have only one list do this:

```
(delete-duplicates '(A B C D E A A B F G A))
```

or

```
(remove-duplicates '(A B C D E A A B F G A))
```

Please check this link for more detail: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_dup.htm#delete-duplicates

Answer (score -1):

```
;;;(setq eva_lst '(A B C D E A A B F G A))
;;;(eva-remove-dupls-in-lst eva_lst)
(defun eva-remove-dupls-in-lst (eva_lst / A_list B_list N)
(setq A_list eva_lst)
(setq B_list '())
(repeat (length A_list)
(setq N (car A_list))
(setq A_list (vl-remove N A_list))
(setq B_list (append B_list (list N)))
  )
(setq B_list (vl-remove 'nil B_list))
  )
;(A B C D E F G)
```